# How to check a specified string is a valid URL or not using C++ code

Tags: c++, windows, validation, url, visual-c++

there any possible way to check that the specified string is a valid url or not. The solution must be in c++ and it should work without internet.

example strings are

```
good.morning
foo.goo.koo
https://hhhh
hdajdklbcbdhd
8881424.www.hfbn55.co.in/sdfsnhjk
://dgdh24.vom
dfgdfgdf(2001)/.com/sdgsgh
\adiihsdfghnhg.co.inskdhhj
aser//www.gtyuh.co.uk/kdsfgdfgfrgj
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chose a symphatetic regular expression like `/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/`.

Use [std regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex), or [boost regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) if you don't have C++11:

```
if (std::regex_match ("http://subject", std::regex("^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$") )) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use *regex*.
[What a regex is.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

With C++11 the regex are build-in the STD library
[regex c++11](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/).

If you cannot use C++11, for some reason, you could use boost library.

Anyway you could check the patter of an url with:

```
#include <regex> //require c++11
// ...

// regex pattern
std::string pattern = "https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)";

// Construct regex object
std::regex url_regex(pattern);

// An url-string for example
std::string my_url = "http://www.google.com/img.png";

// Check for match
if (std::regex_match(my_url, url_regex) == true) {
  std::cout << "This is a well-formed url\n";
} else {
  std::cout << "Ill-formed url\n";
}
```

Comment: From [this site](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) you can find the regex which better fits your needs.

Comment: You need to escape back slashes (add another slash) to embed in string literal used to initialize `pattern`.